# Rotate an associative array so that it begins with a nominated key

Tags: php, arrays, rotation, key, shift

I was working with an array that I need to manipulate maintaining the keys. The `array_shift()` function, which I need to implement, unfortunately does not maintains the key of the processed element of the array. Please see the example code below:

```
$rotor = array ("A" => "R", "B" => "D", "C" => "O", "D" => "B");

$position = "C";

foreach ($rotor as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != $position) {
        $temp = array_shift($rotor);
        array_push($rotor, $temp);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($rotor);
```

Result

```
array(4) {
 ["C"]=>
 string(1) "O"
 ["D"]=>
 string(1) "B"
 [0]=>
 string(1) "R"
 [1]=>
 string(1) "D"
}
```

As you can see, the keys of the `R` and `D` elements aren't the original ones. What alternative solution do you recommend to extract a first element of an array keeping unchanged the key?

P.S: My goal is to extract the first element of the array (keeping the key), and if it is not equivalent to the variable `$position`, insert the element itself in the last position of the array always maintaining its key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rotor = array ("A" => "R", "B" => "D", "C" => "O", "D" => "B");
$position = "C";

foreach ($rotor as $key => $value) {
if($key != $position) {
    array_shift($rotor);
    $rotor += array($key=>$value);
} else {
    break;
}
}
```

Try this - works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, the use of your solution implies a separation of the key and the value.. At the end I need to put them back at the end of the array maintaining they're bond.

Comment: You can keep them separate or hold them together in some other array. Frankly I don't get what you want to do, so this was easiest way for me to get that key.

Comment: My goal is to extract the first element of the array (keeping the key), and if it is not equivalent to the variable $position, insert the element itself in the last position of the array always maintaining its key.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative technique which may perform better or worse depending on the volume of data and the location of the new starting element involves slicing the second half from the array and replacing the original array onto the end.  This effectively places the earlier occurring keys to the back of the array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1lFTE))

```
$rotor = ["A" => "R", "B" => "D", "C" => "O", "D" => "B"];
$from = "C";

foreach (array_keys($rotor) as $index => $key) {
    if ($key === $from) {
        $rotor = array_slice($rotor, $index, null, true) + $rotor;
        break;
    }
}
var_export($rotor);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'C' => 'O',
  'D' => 'B',
  'A' => 'R',
  'B' => 'D',
)
```

This only ever make 1 function call within the loop instead of calling `array_shift()` over and over until the sought key is encountered.

This technique is safe/reliable even if the sought key is in the first element or doesn't occur in the array at all.